# why r-value is being assigned to variable inside array subscript

Tags: arrays, c++11, post-increment

I'm having a problem in push function. Variable inside array subscript(top) is being initialized with r-value(item).

1. When I do the same operation with top=0 it works fine.
2. The problem occurs only when top=-1.
3. In the second and third function call,value of top is incremented sequentially and is not initialized by r-value(item)
4. I have printed the top value each time to ease up debugging.

   ```
   class stack
   {

   int top;
   public:
       int arr[500];

       stack()
       {
           top=-1;
       }

       void push(int);

   };

   void stack::push(int item)
   {


   arr[top++]=item;
   cout<<"\n"<<item<<"pushed in stack";
   cout<<"\n top value is"<<top;

   }
   int main()
   {   
       stack s;
       s.push(12);
       s.push(19);
       s.push(31);
       return 0;
    }
   ```

I expected the output as"12 pushed in stack and top value =0, but the actual output is 12 pushed in stack and top value is 12

Comment: Your first `arr[top++]=item;` writes into `arr[-1]`, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: yes, but why top value is initialized by item not some arbitrary constant. Does this have anything to do with the associativity of operators?

Comment: No, it just means that on your particular conditions `top` was stored right before `arr` and got trampled by the rogue store.